# Android app layout: elements appear on different places

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing Android version of our iOS app, but having layout issues. Elements appear on different places on different screen sizes. Here's the iOS counterpart I have to replicate.
[iPhone's layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrNAQ.png)

Here's my app. What will be the best layout combination to replicate the iOS counterpart.

Here's my version:

[Android layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11VG.png)

Here's the xml of my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rssi"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_indicators_disconnect" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rssi_val"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_rssi"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/searching_all_off_circle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_rssi_val"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_CheckLister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_45sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/searching_all_off" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_btnLock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_parked_location"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_unlock"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_65sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/unlock_unpressed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lock"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_65sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/lock_unpressed" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_parked_location"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ble_list_devices"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/parked_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ble_list_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#565656"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="Searching..."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a `RelativeLayout`, which aligns its contents relative to the root element in the ViewGroup. According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) -

> RelativeLayout is a view group that displays child views in relative
>   positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to
>   sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in
>   positions relative to the parent RelativeLayout area (such as aligned
>   to the bottom, left or center).

In my opinion, elements should adjust their positions accordingly for all screen sizes, and for that, there is a better option than the RelativeLayout, and that is the [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), which works similar to how [ConstraintLayout on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code. Since I'm not having corresponding images I used ic_launcher image to all images you can replace it, wrt your requirement here is the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rssi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rssi_val"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_rssi"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="12dp" />



        <ImageButton
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_rssi_val"
            android:id="@+id/btn_CheckLister"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="45dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@null"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rl_btnLock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_parked_location"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_unlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_lock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_parked_location"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ble_list_devices"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ble_list_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#565656"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Searching..."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```